# How to look at the parameters of a pytorch model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, openai-gym

I have a simple pytorch neural net that I copied from [openai](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py), and I modified it to some extent (mostly the input).

When I run my code, the output of the network remains the same on every episode, as if no training occurs.

I want to see if any training happens, or if some other reason causes the results to be the same.

How can I make sure any movement happens to the weights?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you are doing, but the easiest would be to check the weights of your model.

You can do this (and compare with the ones from previous iteration) using the following code:

```
for parameter in model.parameters():
    print(parameter.data)
```

If the weights are changing, the neural network is being optimized (which doesn't necessarily mean it learns anything useful in particular).